# Cannot find ramaze that is installed with gems

Tags: ruby, ramaze

I have Ramaze version 2012.04.14, Rubygems 1.3.6 and Ruby 1.8.6 so I have the latest version. My console recognises Ramaze and all associated commands. (I can run `ramaze --version`)

I have made a folder inside my `www/` folder inside my localhost environment where public files go.

`www/demo/hello_ramaze.rb` with the [code as explained in the tutorial](http://ramaze.net/documentation/index.html#Quick_Example) as the file.

```
require 'ramaze'

class MyController < Ramaze::Controller
  map '/'

  def index
    return "Hello, Ramaze!"
  end
end

Ramaze.start
```

I try to execute `ruby hello_ramaze.rb` and I get this error.

> hello_ramaze.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- ramaze
>   (LoadError)
>           from hello_ramaze.rb:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3 and the problem is solved.

If you use Windows, use [Rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org).